# Standalone clojure app

Tags: clojure, classnotfoundexception, leiningen

I'm a beginner with clojure, only starting it yesterday.

I have gathered that a simple way to create a standalone app is with leiningen `lein new foo`.

I tried to create a hello world test project with leiningen. I added :main and :aot directives to project.clj, added :gen-class to the core.clj file and tried `lein run`, but I get errors about class definition not found.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
```

The core.clj file

```
(ns test.core
  (:gen-class))
(defn -main [& args] (println "Hello main"))
```

And the project.clj file

```
(defproject test "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write description"
  :main test.core
  :aot [test.core]
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.2.1"]])
```

*Edit:* After further testing, it seems like copying the project to my desktop works as is, which I think points to that the environment on my laptop is somehow borked, but I don't know how.

The environment on desktop is clojure from repositories and leiningen from AUR. On laptop the clojure is from clojure.org and leining is from github.

Comment: What is your CLASSPATH set to?

Comment: @deong my $HOME/bin/clj file has "CLASSPATH=.:$CLASSPATH"

Comment: What happens if you just do an "export CLASSPATH=.:$CLASSPATH" in the shell and then run 'lein run'? I don't believe leiningen calls the clj shell script to run your program. I think it calls java directly with the clojure jar file as an argument.

Comment: @deong Still the same. Or rather, it can't even create the jar file. lein compile gives the same error

Comment: Hmm...I'm drawing a blank then. The clojure code looks right to me.

Comment: what happens when you run lein uberjar and run it with java -jar xxx.jar

Comment: @Hamza it doesn't create the jar file. Ends with the same error

Comment: which folder are you at when you are running the commands?

Comment: @Hamza project root. I might also add that copying the project dir to my desktop, it works. Something must be wrong with my clojure/lein installation

Comment: Could anyone with enough points create a new tag for the question - leiningen-v1 would work. In lein2 the question and the answers would make no sense. lein new changed and the other pieces are all created by default with lein new app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. I had the latest leiningen from git, which was borked somehow. I checked out the 1.6.1 tag and ran self-install, and now it works.

Comment: I have installed git from the repository in Ubuntu and I have the same issue. Should I use the git version too?

Answer (score 35):

**[UPDATE April 2013]**

Leiningen 2, which has been officially released for some time, includes the concept of project templates. By default, Leiningen provides an `app` template that provides what you need out of the box. Try:

`lein new app my-project`

You will see that Leiningen creates the familiar project template, but also includes:

- The default namespace of `my-project.core` as the `:main` entry in your `project.clj` file
- The `:gen-class` form in the namespace declaration of `my-project.core`
- A default `-main` function in the `my-project.core` namespace

For those who cannot yet use Leiningen 2, the [lein-newnew](https://github.com/Raynes/lein-newnew) plugin provides an equivalent experience under Leiningen 1.

**[/UPDATE]**

To build a project that, when run, prints "Hello World!", you'd do as follows (revision of your process above):

### Setup

```
lein new my-project
cd my-project
lein deps
```

You should now have a basic structure in place and the Clojure jar in your `lib` folder.

### Write a Function

Now edit `src/my_project/core.clj` with your editor of choice, adding the following below the `(ns ...)` form:

```
(defn -main []
  (println "Hello World!"))
```

This function is inside your `my-project.core` namespace. To ensure this gets run as your main, let's add a `gen-class` parameter to your namespace definition at the top, so that it now looks like this at the top of `core.clj`:

```
(ns my-project.core
  (:gen-class :main true))
```

So all together, your `core.clj` file looks like this:

```
(ns my-project.core
  (:gen-class :main true))

(defn -main []
  (println "Hello World!"))
```

### Configure it as the Main Function

Once you've got `src/my_project/core.clj` edited as above, you need to tell Leiningen (the build tool) where the "main" function for your project lives. Here's an example `defproject` form that does this:

```
(defproject my-project "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "My Project"
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.2.1"]]
  :main my-project.core)
```

Now the `-main` function inside `my-project.core` becomes the entry-point for your program.

### Run It

You can now have two options for running this project:

- Use `lein run` at the command-line while at the root of your `my-project` project
- Create a standalone jar file by running `lein uberjar`. You can then run the resultant jar file by running `java -jar my-project-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-standalone.jar`

Comment: As my edit says, I think the error is in my laptop environment as the project compiles ok when copied directly to desktop. However a great post, so I'll upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

I missed it, You named your project test, you can't do that change the name to something else it will work.

Answer (score -1):

You say above

```
lein new foo
```

what you mean is

```
lein new test
```

Comment: Ah I see why you thought that, but I did use lein new test